# Jboss ws, auto decode soap message from utf

Tags: web-services, servlets, soap, jboss, jbossws

I've done servlet and deployed it into JBoss. Servlet is working as web service. All is working correctly. But, when my client sends SOAP  message on server. JBoss decodes this message from UTF to ASCII. In other words, when message goes away from client, it's in UTF-8, when it is coming in @webmethod it already in ASCII. So, i think, JBOSS  automatically decodes  this message.

So, i dont need it.. And i cant understand, how can i stop it.